# What is dd doing at the end of copying an image to disk

Tags: ubuntu, dd, disk-image

Today I've copied a 4GB image to a SD card. I noticed that copying the image took about 421 seconds. It showed it had copied 4294967296 bytes. After that dd seemed to do nothing but the command prompt didn't appear either so I've decided to wait. After about 606 seconds dd mentioned that it had read 1024+0 records and had written 1024+0 records and also showed again it had copied 4294967296 bytes. I wonder what is dd doing during this 185 seconds timespan?

The command I used:

```
dd if=image.img of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

Comment: I've added the command to the post.

Comment: I don't know for sure but I suspect it's flushing the in-memory disk cache.

Comment: By the way you'll find `cat image.img > /dev/sdb` no slower, and possibly somewhat faster, than your `dd` command.

Comment: I didn't know that cat could be used like this. I'll try it next time.